# video.js inside a modal window: full screen not working

Tags: modal-dialog, video.js

I've been using video.js to show stuff inside a modal windows, as you can see here:

http://www.csdalbenga.it/galleria1.html

by clicking on the "Clicca qui per visionare il video della recita!" button.

So, here's the problem: video works fine, but the full screen button will just make the video fill the modal window, so basically nothing happens or there's a slight size change depending on the browser.

Now I was wondering, is there a way to force the video to full screen?
Otherwise I guess I'll have to remove the button.

Answer (score 4):

Your modal puts the player in an iframe, and the browser will not allow fullscreen from within an iframe unless you specifically allow it. The following will work in Chrome and Firefox at least; Internet Explorer has not implemented allowing fullscreen from an iframe at all.

```
<iframe … allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true">
```

Comment: I'd rather it worked the same on all platforms. Better to just remove the button. What's the best way to remove it?