# How does Youtube iframe go fullscreen?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, embed, fullscreen

I'm developing an iframe, but impossible to go fullscreen from inside the iframe.
I can go fullscreen with the fullscreen API from inside the iframe when the iframe and the hosting website are on the same domain.
I can also trigger fullscreen from outside the iframe.

But I can't trigger fullscreen from inside the iframe when the hosting website is on a different domain, because of cross-domain policy.

However, YouTube can do this. Do you know how they do it ? Impossible to find out their workaround on the web.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319531/video-js-inside-a-modal-window-full-screen-not-working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found a library that does perfectly the job:
https://github.com/bdougherty/BigScreen